# C-Wire Adapter without Y wire on board

Tags: thermostat, air-conditioning, thermostat-c-wire

I was looking to get our AC thermostat replaced with a smart one.  We have an outside unit, upper unit, and the thermostat.  I checked it out and no surprise, there was no C-Wire in use or hidden anywhere that I could find.  Thermostat has Rc, Y, and G wires. (Heating is baseboard so not tied to this).

I'm certainly not an expert but the C-Wire adapter looked easy enough as opposed to running a new wire.  When I looked at the upper unit control board we have however I wasn't clear on how exactly to wire it up.

There is a G wire and R wire which show as going down to the thermostat.  However the diagram seems to show that the Y wire on the thermostat runs to the outside unit, and then a separate C wire on the board also runs to the outside unit.  This lines up with what I'm seeing - there is no Y terminal on the board and there is one connected to C which looks to be a different wire than the Y on the thermostat, so the diagram seems accurate to me.

For the G and R, the adapter seems straightforward, but I'm not really sure what to do with the Y as the instructions say that I will relabel the Y to K.  Should I plug the C from the outside unit into the Y on the C-wire adapter?  Not really sure exactly how to handle this and looking for any advice.

Diagram Below

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: I take it the cable up to the thermostat only has 3 wires in it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, the thermostat has Y, G, and Rc and that's it.  Control unit in attic has G, C, and R connected.  C on the upper unit is clearly a different wire than then Y on the thermostat, so it seems that the diagram pictured on my unit is accurate and that the C and Y from the upper unit and thermostat are going to the outdoor unit.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both ends please?